# 2d data to 3d data in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have the following data. (individual=2, time=3, so 1,2,3 are for individual 1, and 4,5,6 are for individual 2)

```
     Y1   Y2 X1   X2 X3       Z1        Z2       Z3
1 20.56 0.40  1 6.38  3 5.412649  9.439068 4.471056
2 21.17 0.33  1 6.70  3 5.193636  8.898775 4.442006
3 21.48 0.39  1 6.74  3 7.077044  9.748003 3.286804
4 22.12 0.62  1 6.83  4 7.685389 10.099790 2.569721
5 22.12 0.64  1 6.83  5 7.981264 10.342030 2.670692
6 21.36 0.34  1 6.78  4 8.287524 10.536250 1.420523
```

I want to transform the above 2 dimensional array into 3 dimensional array, (3,8,2) array.
So,

```
data(,,1)=
     Y1   Y2 X1   X2 X3       Z1        Z2       Z3
1 20.56 0.40  1 6.38  3 5.412649  9.439068 4.471056
2 21.17 0.33  1 6.70  3 5.193636  8.898775 4.442006
3 21.48 0.39  1 6.74  3 7.077044  9.748003 3.286804

data(,,2)=
     Y1   Y2 X1   X2 X3       Z1        Z2       Z3
4 22.12 0.62  1 6.83  4 7.685389 10.099790 2.569721
5 22.12 0.64  1 6.83  5 7.981264 10.342030 2.670692
6 21.36 0.34  1 6.78  4 8.287524 10.536250 1.420523
```

I hope someone could help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your expected outcome, I think you are looking for a list. First, you want to create a column with subject ID. Then, you can split your data frame with the variable using `split`. If you need separate data frames, you can use `list2env` and create new data frames in global environment.

```
# Create a column with subject ID
mydf$ID <- rep(c(1,2), each = 3)

# Split your data frame by ID
split(mydf, f = mydf$ID)

#$`1`
#     Y1   Y2 X1   X2 X3       Z1       Z2       Z3 ID
#1 20.56 0.40  1 6.38  3 5.412649 9.439068 4.471056  1
#2 21.17 0.33  1 6.70  3 5.193636 8.898775 4.442006  1
#3 21.48 0.39  1 6.74  3 7.077044 9.748003 3.286804  1

#$`2`
#     Y1   Y2 X1   X2 X3       Z1       Z2       Z3 ID
#4 22.12 0.62  1 6.83  4 7.685389 10.09979 2.569721  2
#5 22.12 0.64  1 6.83  5 7.981264 10.34203 2.670692  2
#6 21.36 0.34  1 6.78  4 8.287524 10.53625 1.420523  2

# If you need to create separate data frames, use list2env.
list2env(split(mydf, f = mydf$ID), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Ah sorry. That is meant to be `mydf`. When I test codes I tend to use person names. I change that now!

Answer (score 2):

If you really do want an array, since it is all numeric data, you can do

```
s <- split(df, rep(1:2, nrow(df)/2))
array(unlist(s), c(3, 8, 2))
# , , 1
# 
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]     [,6]      [,7]     [,8]
# [1,] 20.56 0.40    1 6.38    3 5.412649  9.439068 4.471056
# [2,] 21.48 0.39    1 6.74    3 7.077044  9.748003 3.286804
# [3,] 22.12 0.64    1 6.83    5 7.981264 10.342030 2.670692
# 
# , , 2
# 
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]     [,6]      [,7]     [,8]
# [1,] 21.17 0.33    1 6.70    3 5.193636  8.898775 4.442006
# [2,] 22.12 0.62    1 6.83    4 7.685389 10.099790 2.569721
# [3,] 21.36 0.34    1 6.78    4 8.287524 10.536250 1.420523
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an external package named 'abind' that has a function by the same name that makes this pretty easy. The only try part is figuring out that you need to tell it you want a third dimension. Since it is after the ellipsis in the argument list the 'along' argument must be named:

```
require(abind)
arr <- abind( split( dat, rep(1:2, 3) ), along=3)
arr[, , 1] 
#----------
     Y1   Y2 X1   X2 X3       Z1        Z2       Z3
2 20.56 0.40  1 6.38  3 5.412649  9.439068 4.471056
4 21.48 0.39  1 6.74  3 7.077044  9.748003 3.286804
6 22.12 0.64  1 6.83  5 7.981264 10.342030 2.670692

arr[,,2]

     Y1   Y2 X1   X2 X3       Z1        Z2       Z3
2 21.17 0.33  1 6.70  3 5.193636  8.898775 4.442006
4 22.12 0.62  1 6.83  4 7.685389 10.099790 2.569721
6 21.36 0.34  1 6.78  4 8.287524 10.536250 1.420523
```

The requested calling strategy cannot be exactly followed since the parentheses cannot be used for index and you must us square-brackets. And I'm afraid the row numbers didn't survive intact.